# Why Transition css is not working in child selector css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a dropdown in button hover,
I also try the transition css property on my code but its not working to come dropdown smoothly.

This below code is bootstrap dropdown code please suggest me to where i put the right code

```css
.dropdown {
                  position: relative;
                  display: inline-block;
                }
                
                .dropdown-content {
                  display: none;
                }
                .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
                  display: block;
                  top: 35px;
                }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown p-0">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                   dropdown
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-arrow"></div>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-content">
                      <li> <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="fe fe-file-text mr-2"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i>Add Task</a></li>
                        <li> <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="fe fe-zap mr-2"
                          aria-hidden="true"></i>Add Risk</a></li>
                          <li> <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="fe fe-trending-up mr-2"
                            aria-hidden="true"></i>Add Milestone</a></li>
                    <li> <a class="dropdown-item" ><i class="fe fe-trash-2 mr-2"
                          aria-hidden="true"></i>Remove Me form This Project</a> </li>
                    <li> <a class="dropdown-item" ><i class="fe fe-edit mr-2"
                          aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit</a> </li>
                    <li> <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="fe fe-check-circle mr-2"
                          aria-hidden="true"></i>Complete</a></li>
                          
                  </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself** [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't share all the code, first of all you can't add transition at display property, you didn't add transition for top property.

Try to hide `.downtown-content` with `transform: translateY(-100%)`, and then in hover 
`transform: translateY(0); transition: all .25s linear` (or add your transition here)

Comment: Thank you for helping, but Its not working in hover working on click but only in first click.it's not coming in second time  when clicking...

Comment: .dropdown-content {
                  position: relative;
                  transform: translateY(-120%);
                  transition: all .25s linear;
                }
                .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
                  transform: translateY(0);
                  transition: all .25s linear; 
                }

try this, you also should wrap dropdown-content with another div and give that div overflow: hidden